# Illegal start of expression? BlueJ

Tags: java

Not sure why it happens, I tried removing the "public" and I still get 1 million other errors

```
public class Script0 {
    public static void main() {   
    int[] score = new int[ - 0];

   public Keying(Display d) {
   d.f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            score ++;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_META) {
            score--;
        }
        }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: The signature of `main` is wrong. And you can't embed a `Keying` constructor in the `main` method in the `Script0` class. Finally, an array of `-0` length isn't particularly useful.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. Like indentation, lack of arguments in `main` method, lack of `}`. Also what is purpose of `new int[-0];` and why constructor of that class is not named same as class itself? You should consider reading basic tutorial before asking any question.

Comment: There are 1 million errors because you don't compile your codes occasionally. I believe there are multiple mistakes in your codes.

Comment: Idk, I'm new to java, my main language is Lua so I put this together using as little knowledge as possible lol

Answer (score -1):

Close the bracket of `main` method, and try to add a `length` of the `score` array like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {   
    int[] score = new int[some_length];
    }
```

And try to add a return value of `Keying` method or use `void`  like this:

```
  public void Keying(Display d) {
  ...
```

To create a constructor without field use like this:

```
  public Script0() {
   ...
  }
```

Comment: What's the signature of the Java [Entry Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#Java)? Also, OP's constructor belongs to another class.